# Not enough permissions to start workflow with read permissions

Tags: workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 portal. I have created a workflow on a list. I have full control permissions and can start the workflow manual. But another user has only read permissions on the site. He cannot start the workflow. Which permissions is needed to start manual a list workflow?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience to manually start a workflow at all in SharePoint 2013 the user needs edit permissions.

If the workflow is being started through "Item Created" or "When Item Changes" you may need to use an app step to modify items in lists. You can find out more about App Steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this...
this.context.Web.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions.EditListItems);

http://zsvipullo.blogspot.it/2014/09/sharepoint-2013-access-denied-opening.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a workflow on a list. 
The user wanted to start te workflow manual only in some situations. 
But it was no option to give this user contribute permissions on the whole site.

To facilitate this I created the following workarround.

I added a choice column to the list (Start Workflow) (Yes/No) (Default value No)

In the workflow I created a condition :
If field start workflow in current item equals yes => do stuff.

When the user edits an item it can set the start workflow value on yes or no depending on whether he/she wants the workflow to start (or not)

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: "Edit" perms on a list is enough for workflow to be (manually/automatically) started on item add/change

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what the workflow does. If it is going to modify something in the list, only users with edit permission will be able to run it.

Comment: it is creating only a task action. Is this possible and what do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: And how do you want to trigger it? With OOB features read-only user hasn't even the ribbon to do it.
Unfortunately it is an open question even here (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44720/workflow-permissions?rq=1). I don't think you can manage ti with read-only permissions in any way.

Comment: but why did you say in your first comment "it depends on what the workflow does"? Are there workflows which are working with read only users? I have now a custom action in the top ribbon. The read only user can see it, but when he clicks on it he gets an error like access denied.

Comment: Because even if you give edit permissions to a user, the system won't run actions not allowed to that user permissions level.
For instance the approval workflow won't work with edit permissions. But at that time you still didn't write what WF does. Now it is clear that it is not your case.

Comment: This isn't relevant. The question was about starting workflows...not permission required for actions to be taken by the workflow. Also the information you provide is false, workflows can run with elevated permissions.

Comment: @Dave. This was an answer to a remark not to a question. About workflow with elevated permissions, please show me an exemple how a read-only user can trigger it directly.

Answer (score -1):

Under List Permission please give Approve Rights